# How do I add a file to a POST request made in Locust.io?

Tags: python, django, locust

I'm using Locust.io to load test a python/django website that accepts image upload::

```
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
image = open('img.jpg', 'rb')
payload = {'id': self.id}
files = {'photo': image}    
upload_result = self.client.post("/image/", data=payload, files=files, headers=headers)
```

When I use the above I see `request.FILES` in Django is `None`. However when I use POSTMAN instead of Locust to do the same thing, I get the files object in `request` in Django.

server.py

```
photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
id = request.POST.get('id')
form = PhotosModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

How do I send the file in the Locust HTTP client request along with some POST data?

Comment: Locust uses `requests` as a transport library. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881885/upload-image-through-form-data-using-python-requests) should work (assuming your Django site receives the file as `multipart/form-data`)